# Search for a string in an array of strings using AND condition

Tags: javascript, search

How do I make `includes()` in `some()` match all cases ?

```js
let instance = ['m6gd.medium', '1 vCPU', '4 GiB'];

// let search = "medium"; // true
// let search = "4gb"; // true
// let search = "medium 4gb"; // true
let search = "medium 12gb"; // true - need to make this false - need AND condition

let found = instance.some(s1 =>
{
    console.log("s1 = ", s1.toLowerCase());

    let search_term = search.toLowerCase();
    search_term = search_term.replace(/gb/g, "gib");
    search_term = search_term.replace(/(\d+)(gib)/g, "$1 $2");

    console.log("search_term = ", search_term);

    return search_term.split(' ').some(s2 =>
        {
            console.log("s2 = ", s2.toLowerCase(), "\n");
            return s1.toLowerCase().includes(s2.toLowerCase())
        });
});

console.log(found);
```

Comment: `every` instead of `some`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array.foreach on the split search term, and in callback for array.foreach test that calling some function on the haystack returns true. here is how I would do it.

```
let instance = ["m6gd.medium", "1 vCPU", "4 GiB"];

// let search = "medium"; // true
// let search = "4gb"; // true
// let search = "medium 4gb"; // true
let search = "medium 12gb"; // true - need to make this false - need AND condition

let search_term = search.toLowerCase();
search_term = search_term.replace(/gb/g, "gib");
search_term = search_term.replace(/(\d+)(gib)/g, "$1 $2");


let notFound = false;
//false for now, but we will split search term, 
//then perform array.foreach on each split item to see if it is contained in instance array. If so, this becomes true

search_term.split(" ").forEach(el => {
  if(!instance.some(s => {
    return s.toLowerCase().includes(el.toLowerCase())
  }))
  {
    notFound = true;
  }
})


console.log(!notFound);
```

Thanks for the question, indeed it appears there is a way without foreach, it may run faster as well. I am not experienced enough to know, but here is the code:

```
let instance = ["m6gd.medium", "1 vCPU", "4 GiB"];

// let search = "medium"; // true
// let search = "4gb"; // true
// let search = "medium 4gb"; // true
let search = "medium 12gb"; // true - need to make this false - need AND condition

let search_term = search.toLowerCase();
search_term = search_term.replace(/gb/g, "gib");
search_term = search_term.replace(/(\d+)(gib)/g, "$1 $2");

let result = compare(search_term.split(" "), instance)


function compare(searchArray, comparisonArray) {
  // Convert all items in the comparison array to lowercase
  const comparisonArrayLowercase = comparisonArray.map((item) => item.toLowerCase());

  // Check if every item in the search array is a substring of at least one item in the comparison array
  return searchArray.every((searchItem) =>
    comparisonArrayLowercase.some(
      (comparisonItem) => comparisonItem.includes(searchItem.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution - I was thinking this could now be solved with ES2022 features or something instead of using a forEach loop.

Comment: No problem, I just learned you can do it without foreach and updated my answer to show how with Array.prototype.every() and Array.prototype.some() methods instead